# How to get button click from a custom data attribute in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would have thought this would have worked for the custom data attribute `data-input-id`  but for some reason I must have the wrong syntax.

```js
$('button[data-input-id="answer3"]').click(function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-input-id="answer3">Skill Booster</button>
```

Comment: It works : https://jsfiddle.net/c3dwbt97/. Do you use $.click after DOM loaded ?

Comment: I see what I did wrong.  From your reply I figured out the order of my code and it was a statement after this one that broke my code. Thanks!